# How to make getpeerurl function always work even if ribbon is hidden in JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom, variations

I want to use the getpeerUrl SharePoint 2013 function in JSOM to get the other variation URL for the current page. I have a solution here

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {

            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
            var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, window.location.pathname, "fr");  
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function() {

                    // CORRESPONDING URL
                    var otherURL = object.get_value();


                }, function(sender, args) {

                }
            );

        }, "sp.publishing.js");
    });
}, "sp.js");
```

and on the master page I have jquery and also I put

```
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.publishing.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True"/>-->
```

However this seems to only work if the ribbon is showing. If it is hidden, then this code doesn't work. Does anyone know how to make getpeerurl always work?

Like do I need to import more sp javascript libraries in masterpage or something?

Thanks